# Adding upper/lower cap to geom_smooth smoothed line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, smoothing

I want to have a cap to the smoothed line produced with geom_line (ggplot2) using the loess method. My data do not go above 1, but the smoothed line does.

The only post I found in this regard is from 2012. However, the problem did not receive a solution
(see the following link: https://groups.google.com/g/ggplot2/c/Mxsbb4p3V7Y).

For convenience I reprise the working example originally posted by the person posing the question here. I hope this will not create too much trouble. As noted by the same person, the smoothed line goes below 0, although min(y) = 0.007593811.

```
library(ggplot2)
y<-rep(0:1,each=20,times=5)+runif(10,0,0.05)
x<-seq(1:length(y))
ggplot()+geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_smooth(aes(x=x,y=y),method='loess',span=0.20,se=F)
```

Is it possible to add a upper/lower cap for geom_smooth, such that the values of the smoothed line produced with the loess method lie within a specific range (e.g., 0 and 1)? Thank you all.

**EDIT**

Thank you both for the great solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example includes values of greater than 1, so let's make an equivalent data set that doesn't go above 1:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:200, 
                 y = ifelse(rep(0:1 == 0, each = 20, times = 5), 
                            runif(200)/20, runif(200, 0.95, 1)))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess', span = 0.20, se = FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0, 1), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Although we could simply clamp the loess to the range [0, 1], a slightly more sophisticated approach would be to perform a logit transformation, regress on *that*, then reverse the transform. This gives a smoother result:

```r
df$logit_y <- log(df$y/(1 - df$y)) # logit transform
df$pred <- predict(loess(logit_y ~ x, data = df, span = 0.2))
df$pred <- exp(df$pred)/(exp(df$pred) + 1) # Reverse logit

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(y = pred), color = "blue", linewidth = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0, 1), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be accomplished using [delayed evaluation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) so that the smooth value is at the last minute capped to the desired range:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=stage(y, after_stat = pmax(0,pmin(1, y)))),
              method='loess', span=0.20, se = FALSE)
```

[image]